# Detecting RHEL/RPM based distros

Tags: rhel, rpm

I'm trying to write a script to detect if it's being run on RHEL/RPM based distros.

I've faced some odd systems configured such that both `dpkg` and `rpm` are installed, so doing a `which rpm` isn't a solution.

I attempted this:

```
if [[ "$(cat /etc/*[_-][rv]e[lr]*)" == (CentOS|Fedora) ]]; then
  #...
fi
```

but this requires me to know the names of all distributions that are based on RHEL/RPM.

Comment: If you are open to use other utilities, facter is exactly the tool for this task. http://puppetlabs.com/facter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is to detect whether `rpm` is the package manager on that system, a good heuristic should be that the RPM package database is not empty.

```
if [ -n "$(rpm -qa)" ] 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "This looks like an rpm-based system"
else
  echo "Either there is no rpm command, or the rpm package database has no entries"
fi
```

Comment: Very clever indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/os-release` file contains the `ID_LIKE=` field, which is for identifying the base distribution that the local OS is derived from. You can check if it contains `rhel` with `grep`:

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep ID_LIKE= | grep rhel
```

More documentation on this file: [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html).

Comment: have no /etc/os-release oh my centos'es...

Comment: @ror6ax Strange...

Comment: either way, this is a new good practice, so this should be looked for as well, +1 to that

Answer (score 0):

I would check presence of /etc/redhat-release or /etc/fedora-release.

Comment: A question: would `/etc/redhat-release` be present in ones like OpenSuSE or Mageia?

Comment: /etc/SuSE-release and /etc/mageia-release, respectively.
please consider @psimon's answer as all this zoo of files is finally getting standartisized(whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You can check output of `/proc/version`:

```
$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.14.8-200.fc20.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.phx2.fedoraproject.org) 
(gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Jun 16 21:57:53 UTC 2014
```

Example:

```
$ grep -q 'Red Hat' /proc/version && echo "Redhat based distro"
Redhat based distro
```